CSS for Page break when generating a form using FTL
I have been beating my head into the wall trying to get this form to format correctly when printed. The problem I have is that when I try to tell it where to insert page breaks manually, it still does things like breaking in the middle of tables as well as inserting blank pages randomly. I am sure it must be something simple i am missing but after a week of tinkering- I am finally reaching out to the community.
first off- I am only a novice programer and my HTML CSS skills are pretty limited. I have tried adding the following style with almost no effect.
.page-break {
            break-after: always;
            break-before: always;
            margin-top: 40px; /* Optional: to add some space before the new page content starts */
        }       
    /* Table handling */
    table {
        page-break-inside: auto;
        border-collapse: collapse; /* Ensure proper table rendering */
    }
    
    tr {
        break-inside: avoid; /* Avoid breaking inside rows */
        break-after: auto; /* Allow break after rows */
    }

    /* Handling dividers and spacing */
    hr {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }

    .divider {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        break-after: avoid;
    }

    /* General page break avoidance for divs */
    div {
        break-inside: avoid;
        break-after: auto;
    }
}

And here is the full HTML in it's current state where I am now trying to use inline style adding divs specifically to attempt a forced page break...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Termite Inspection Report</title>
     
     <style>
      /* Centering the entire content of the body */
        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
              /* Vertically centers the content */
            align-items: center;      /* Horizontally centers the content */
            min-height: 100vh;        /* Ensures the content is centered within the full viewport height */
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            text-align: center;       /* Centers text inside block elements */
        }

        .logo {
            width: 400px;
        }
     
                 /* Divider styling */
        .divider {
            width: 100%;
            height: 35px;
            background-color: #fbd351;
            margin: 20px 0;
        } 
        .alert {
            color: red;
        }
            /* Styling images specifically within tables */
        table img {
            max-width: 275px; /* Adjust this value as needed for larger images */
            height: auto;
        }

        table {
            
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 20px 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 10px;
            border: 3px solid #ccc;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>

    <#if logoUrl?has_content>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="${logoUrl}">
    </div>
    </#if>
    
    <h1>Annual Termite Inspection Report</h1>
    <#if homephoto.imageUrl?has_content>
    <img src="${homephoto.imageUrl}" width="600">
    </#if>
    <h1> ${serviceFullAddress}</h1>
    <h2> ${apptDate}</h2>
    <p style="break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p><!-- MANUAL PAGE BREAK HERE!!!!! -->
    <div class="section content"><!-- Customer Info -->
        <h2 class = "divider">Customer Information</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Account #</th>
                <td>${accountId}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Name on Account</th>
                <td>${customerFullName}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Service Address</th>
                <td>${serviceFullAddress}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Email Address</th>
                <td>${customerEmail}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                <td>${customerPrimaryPhone}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Inspector's Name</th>
                <td>${techName}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    <div class="section"><!-- Termite Activity Summary -->
        <h2 class = "divider">Termite Activity</h2>
        <p>${termite.termiteActivity} ${sum.treat?string('A treatment was performed. Please see the attached diagram.','No treatments were performed.')}</p>
        <p style="break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p><!-- MANUAL PAGE BREAK HERE!!!!! -->
        <div class="section content">
    
        <#if (ext?has_content || crawl?has_content || int?has_content)>
        <h2>Summary of action items.</h2><!-- ALERT SUMMARY-->
        <p>The items described below must be corrected by the homeowner.</p>
        <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Photo</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Exterior Photos with Alerts -->
            <#if ext?has_content>
            <#list ext as item>
                <#if item.action?has_content>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <#if item.exphoto.imageUrl?has_content>
                            <img src="${item.exphoto.imageUrl}" width="150">
                        <#else>
                            No photo available.
                        </#if>
                    </td>
                    <td>Exterior</td>
                    <td>${item.exPhotodes!"No description provided."}</td>
                </tr>
                </#if>
            </#list>
            </#if>
            <!-- Crawlspace Photos with Alerts -->
            <#if crawl?has_content>
            <#list crawl as item>
                <#if item.action?has_content>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <#if item.crawlphoto.imageUrl?has_content>
                            <img src="${item.crawlphoto.imageUrl}" width="150">
                        <#else>
                            No photo available.
                        </#if>
                    </td>
                    <td>Crawlspace</td>
                    <td>${item.crawlphotodes!"No description provided."}</td>
                </tr>
                </#if>
            </#list>
            </#if>
            <!-- Interior Photos with Alerts -->
            <#if int?has_content>
            <#list int as item>
                <#if item.action?has_content>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <#if item.intphoto.imageUrl?has_content>
                            <img src="${item.intphoto.imageUrl}" width="150">
                        <#else>
                            No photo available.
                        </#if>
                    </td>
                    <td>Interior</td>
                    <td>${item.intphotodes!"No description provided."}</td>
                </tr>
                </#if>
            </#list>
            </#if>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <#else>
    <p>No alert photos available.</p>
    </#if>
</div>

    </div>
    <p style="break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p><!-- MANUAL PAGE BREAK HERE!!!!! -->
    <div class="section inspection-question content"><!------------- EXT PERIMETER INSPECTION -->
        <h2 class = "divider">Exterior Perimeter Inspection</h2>
        
        
        
        <table class= "inspection-question">
            <tr>
               <th>Are any areas inaccessible or obstructed?</th>
               <td>${exterior.inaccessible?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
               <td>Obstructed areas limit visibility and prevent a thorough inspection, increasing the risk of missed issues.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>Wood destroying fungi damage/rot present?</th>
               <td>${exterior.fungiRot?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
               <td>Wood rot indicates moisture damage, which can weaken structural integrity and invite termite infestations.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>Is there adequate clearance (6 inches) between the ground and siding?</th>
               <td>${exterior.clearance?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
               <td>Adequate clearance prevents soil contact, reducing the risk of termite entry into the structure.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Is there wood in contact with the ground?</th>
                <td>${exterior.woodtoground?string('Yes','No')}</td>
                <td>Wood-to-ground contact is a common termite entry point, as termites can easily access and feed on the wood.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Is there any firewood/stored wood next to or against/touching the structure?</th>
                <td>${exterior.firewood?string('Yes','No')}</td>
                <td>Storing wood near the home provides termites with a food source close to the structure, increasing infestation risk.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>Are any trees touching the structure?</th>
               <td>${exterior.trees?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
               <td>Trees in contact with the home provide a bridge for termites and pests to enter the building.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>Is there proper drainage / water diversion from the home's foundation?</th>
               <td>${exterior.drain?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
               <td>Poor drainage can lead to moisture buildup, which attracts termites and encourages wood decay.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Does the structure have a crawlspace or Walkunder area?</th>
                <td>${exterior.foundationcrawl?string('Yes','No')}</td>
                <td>Crawlspaces require special attention as they are prone to moisture issues and can harbor termites undetected.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <#if stationsInspected?has_content>  
          <p style="break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p><!-- MANUAL PAGE BREAK HERE!!!!! -->
          <div>
          <img src="https://assets.corteva.com/is/image/Corteva/Sentricon%20logo%20RGB">
          <p>The Sentricon system is a trusted termite baiting solution designed to protect homes and properties from termite infestations. It uses bait stations strategically placed around the property to eliminate termite colonies. These stations contain a slow-acting bait that termites ingest and share with the colony, ultimately eliminating it. Sentricon is environmentally friendly and requires no invasive drilling or chemical spraying.</p>
        <table width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
            <#list stationsInspected?sort_by("stationId") as station>
            <tr>
                <td>${station.description!}</td>
                <td>${station.indicator!}</td>
                <td>${station.activity?string('Yes','No')}</td>
                <td>${station.comments!"No comments"}</td>
            
            </tr>
            </#list>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
       
       
        </#if>

        <p style="break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p><!-- MANUAL PAGE BREAK HERE!!!!! -->
    <#if ext?has_content><!--------------------- Exterior Photos -->
        <div class="section content">
        <h2>Exterior Photos</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Photo</th>
                    <th>Risk & Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <#list ext as item>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <#if item.exphoto.imageUrl?has_content>
                                <img src="${item.exphoto.imageUrl}">
                            <#else>
                                No photo available.
                            </#if>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h2>${item.risk} Risk</h2>
                            <#if item.exPhotodes?has_content>
                                ${item.exPhotodes}
                            <#else>
                                No description provided.
                            </#if>
                            <#if item.action?has_content>
                                <h3 class="alert">*Home Owner Action Needed*</h3>
                            </#if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </#list>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </#if>
    <p style= break-after: always;>&nbsp;</p><!-- MANUAL PAGE BREAK HERE!!!!! -->
    <#if exterior.foundationcrawl><!-- Crawlspace Inspection -->
        <div class="inspection-question section content">
        <h2 class = "divider">Crawlspace/Walkunder Inspection</h2>
        <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Were there any areas that were not accessible for inspection?</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.inaccessible?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
        <td>Inaccessible crawlspaces can conceal termite activity and moisture issues, increasing the risk of future problems.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>The crawlspace contains debris and/or stored materials?</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.debris?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
        <td>Debris and stored materials can hide termite activity and retain moisture, promoting infestations.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Is there a moisture barrier covering the soil?</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.moisturebarrior?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
        <td>A moisture barrier prevents excessive ground moisture from entering the crawlspace, reducing termite attraction.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Is there adequate clearance (min 3 inches) between the liner and subfloor system?</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.inspectiongap?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
        <td>Adequate clearance helps ensure that moisture doesn't accumulate against the structure, preventing wood decay.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Subfloor insulation type?</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.insulationtype}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Is insulation hanging or fallen?</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.insulationhang?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
        <td>Hanging or fallen insulation can indicate moisture issues or other structural concerns in the crawlspace.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Is there standing water and/or faulty grade present? (should be evaluated by a drainage/or gutter expert)</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.standingwater?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
        <td>Standing water or faulty grading can contribute to excessive moisture, increasing the risk of termite activity.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Is there evidence of crawlspace moisture problems, fungi damage/stains, or condensation visible?</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.moistureissues?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
        <td>Visible moisture problems, fungi damage, or stains indicate high moisture levels that can lead to wood decay and attract termites.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Crawlspace Wood Moisture Content</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.moisturecontent}%</td>
        <td>Monitoring the wood moisture content helps in assessing the potential for decay or termite activity.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Plumbing leaks?</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.plumbingleaks?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
        <td>Plumbing leaks or condensation can create moisture problems, which attract termites and cause structural damage.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Are there any dirt-filled areas (porches, chimney, etc.)?</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.dirt?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
        <td>Dirt-filled areas near the structure can increase moisture levels and provide a conducive environment for termites.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Is there visible moisture damage or rot in the crawlspace?</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.fungiRot?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
        <td>Moisture damage and wood rot indicate water issues, which can attract termites and other pests.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Are there any plumbing leaks or HVAC condensation drains discharging in the area?</th>
        <td>${crawlspace.plumbingleaks?string('Yes', 'No')}</td>
        <td>Plumbing leaks or condensation can create moisture problems, which attract termites and cause structural damage.</td>
    </tr>
</table>

        </div>
    </#if>
    <p style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p><!-- MANUAL PAGE BREAK HERE!!!!! -->
    <#if crawl?has_content><!-- Crawlspace Photos -->
        <div class="section content">
        <h2>Crawlspace Photos</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Photo</th>
                    <th>Risk & Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <#list crawl as item>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <#if item.crawlphoto.imageUrl?has_content>
                                <img src="${item.crawlphoto.imageUrl}">
                            <#else>
                                No photo available.
                            </#if>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h2>${item.risk} Risk</h2>
                            <#if item.crawlphotodes?has_content>
                                ${item.crawlphotodes}
                            <#else>
                                No description provided.
                            </#if>
                            <#if item.action?has_content>
                                <h3 class="alert">*Home Owner Action Needed*</h3>
                            </#if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </#list>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </#if>
    <p style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p><!-- MANUAL PAGE BREAK HERE!!!!! -->
<#if interior.inspectint><!-- Interior Inspection -->
    <div class="section inspection-question content">
        <h2 class = "divider">Interior Inspection</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Was an interior inspection completed?</th>
                <td>${interior.inspectint?string('Yes','No')}</td>
                <td>An interior inspection ensures that any signs of termite activity, moisture problems, or structural issues are detected inside the home.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Was an attic inspection completed?</th>
                <td>${interior.attic?string('Yes','No')}</td>
                <td>Attic inspections are crucial, as termites can sometimes enter through roof structures, and moisture can accumulate in poorly ventilated attics.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Are there any areas that were not accessible for inspection, stored items, or personal belongings that limited your inspection?</th>
                <td>${interior.inaccessint?string('Yes','No')}</td>
                <td>Obstructions inside the home, such as stored items, can prevent a thorough inspection, increasing the risk of undetected issues.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Are there any bath tubs without access doors?</th>
                <td>${interior.bath?string('Yes','No')}</td>
                <td>Bath trap access doors allow inspectors to monitor and mitigate termite risks in areas that are often prone to moisture and wood exposure, reducing the chances of undetected infestations.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Are there wood floors present on slab areas?</th>
                <td>${interior.woodfloors?string('Yes','No')}</td>
                <td>Wood floors on slab areas can be more susceptible to moisture buildup, which can create ideal conditions for termites.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Is there evidence of interior moisture problems, fungi damage/stains, or condensation visible? (should be evaluated by a licensed contractor)</th>
                <td>${interior.intmoist?string('Yes','No')}</td>
                <td>Moisture problems, fungi damage, or visible stains inside the home indicate potential leaks or ventilation issues, which can lead to termite infestations.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <p style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p><!-- MANUAL PAGE BREAK HERE!!!!! -->
    <#if int?has_content>
    <div class="section content"><!-- Interior Photos -->
        <h2>Interior Photos</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Photo</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <#list int as item>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <#if item.intphoto.imageUrl?has_content> <!-- Adjust this key based on your data structure -->
                                <img src="${item.intphoto.imageUrl}">
                            <#else>
                                No photo available.
                            </#if>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h2>${item.risk} Risk</h2>
                            <#if item.intphotodes?has_content>
                                ${item.intphotodes}
                            <#else>
                                No description provided.
                            </#if>
                            <#if item.action?has_content>
                                <h3 class="alert">*Home Owner Action Needed*</h3>
                            </#if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </#list>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </#if>
</#if>

   



<footer><!---------------------------------- SIGNATURE AREA-->
    <section class="no-page-break">
        <h2>Signature</h2>

        <div class="signature-container">
            <div class="signature-box-left">
                <div class="border-box signature-box">
                    
                    <#if signature??><div class="signature">${signature}</div>
                    
                    <div class="bottom-label">Homeowner / Authorized Representative Signature</div>
                    <div class="date-label">signed on ${signatureSignDate}</div></#if>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="signature-box-right">
                <div class="border-box signature-box">
                    <div class= "signature">${representative!'&nbsp;'}</div>
                    <div class="bottom-label">Inspector Signature</div>
                    <div class="date-label">signed on ${representativeSignDate!'&nbsp;'}</div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</footer>
</body>
</html>


Any ideas on what i could try to get this to format properly would be great!
